# Cold War SF about man and machine neural interface in aircraft

Tags: story-identification, soft-sci-fi

It's an old work of Science Fiction (written during the Cold War).

The subject is men & machine interface.

The plot is as follows:

- An American pilot flies on a bombing mission to and over Russia.
- The aircraft and he are connected together by the neural networks and they are **actually one**!
- All kind of problems, thoughts and mishaps happen to them during this flight.

Question: What is the name of the book and/or the author?

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: Gaultheria looks like he has the right answer, I'd just add that I don't think that Artificial Neural Networks were a common concept in the 70s so there was probably some other term for the tech.

Answer (score 13):

This sounds like *Firefox*, a [1977 novel](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_(novel)) by Craig Thomas, made into a [1982 film](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_(film)) starring Clint Eastwood.  It's about a plot to steal a Soviet fighter jet that has an experimental thought-controlled interface.

A key point in choosing the American pilot for the mission is that the interface requires the pilot to think in Russian.

Comment: There was also a sequel novel, *Firefox Down*, that picks up where the previous one left off.

Answer (score 1):

A book with similar details is *The Day of the Cheetah*, a [1989 novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day_of_the_Cheetah) by Dale Brown.

> His job at the secret base involves testing the highly advanced
>   XF-34 Dreamstar, which is equipped with a thought-control interface.
>
> James hijacks the fighter, causing Patrick McLanahan and the rest of
>   the HAWC crew to try to recover or destroy the plane before it reaches
>   the USSR.

Comment: Thanks. I will check both books. My memory is a little bit vague about the plot but it seems that none of the two books is the right one.